# Can't find referenced sheet in excel file while trying to read from a webpage in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, oledb

I'm trying to build a webpage that allows a user to choose an excel file and then the page will read the contents of the page and upload the data to the DB after validation.

I have a fileUpload asp control with a button for execution and a gridview to display the data. This isn't the end-goal, but I have it simply to test if the script is reading the file successfully (which it isn't).

The error I keep getting is:

```
"The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."
```

The excel file I upload definitely has a Sheet1, so I'm not sure what's going on.

I won't pretend to have a lot of experience or understanding as how OleDB works, so I'm sure it's something simple.

My Code is as follows:

```
Protected Sub Upload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Upload.Click
    If (testFile.HasFile) Then
        Dim conn As OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim query As String
        Dim connString As String = ""
        Dim strFileType As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(testFile.FileName).ToString().ToLower()

        'Check file type
        If strFileType.Trim = ".xls" Or strFileType.Trim = ".xlsx" Then
        Else
            MsgBox("Only excel files allowed")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Try
            'Connection String to Excel Workbook
            If strFileType.Trim = ".xls" Then
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & testFile.FileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
            ElseIf strFileType.Trim = ".xlsx" Then
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & testFile.FileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
            End If

            query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

            'Create the connection object
            conn = New OleDbConnection(connString)
            'Open connection
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()
            'Create the command object
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            ds = New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)

            grvExcelData.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            grvExcelData.DataBind()

            da.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
            conn.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Must have file")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I'd also appreciate a good resource on how to learn more about OleDB along with the specifics errors of my code!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an output to view the sheets from the page, perhaps in a DropDownList object (this code is a little ugly, but should point you in the right direction).  Basically return your sheets first to verify it exists...

```
 private void ProcessExcelFile(string fileName, bool isOpenXMLFormat)
    {
        string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        String RelativePath = "YourPath/" + fn;
        string connectionString = String.Empty;
        OleDbConnection con;

        if (isOpenXMLFormat)
            //read a 2007 file  
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        else
            //read a 97-2003 file  
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

        con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();

        //get all the available sheets  
        System.Data.DataTable dataSet = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        //get the number of sheets in the file  
        string[] workSheetNames = new String[dataSet.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Rows)
        {
            //insert the sheet's name in the current element of the array  
            //and remove the $ sign at the end  
            //workSheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim(new[] { '$' });
            workSheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            i++;
        }
        SheetNames.DataSource = workSheetNames;
        SheetNames.DataBind();
```

Comment: I thought I could use the datagridview for that. Also, you don't by any chance have this in VB?