# Error when trying to read data from Excel in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

I've tried many different routes in being able to build a page that allows the user to choose an excel file and then reads data from that file. So far all I've gotten is errors.

My latest error is: "Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only."

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub Upload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Upload.Click
    If (testFile.HasFile) Then
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim strFileType As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(testFile.FileName).ToString().ToLower()

        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & testFile.FileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2")

        ' Select the data from Sheet1 ([in-house$]) of the workbook.
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)

        ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(ds) - __This is where the error points.__
        grvExcelData.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas on why this is being thrown? I'm just trying to output the data to a gridview for now. Later I will need to loop through each cell, but I'm trying one step at a time.

Also, if there's a better way to do this I am completely open to it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But `strFileType` is the extension of the file that you wish to open. (I.E. for filename.xls it is just the .xls part)
Probably you want the full file name.

```
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection( _
    "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
    "data source=" & testFile.FileName & "; " & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0")
```

Now, for the 'better part':
You don't close the connection, and this should never happen. 
A simple Using block will save you

```
    Using MyConnection = New OleDbConnection( _
        "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "data source=" & strFileType & "; " & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0")

        ' Select the data from Sheet1 ([in-house$]) of the workbook.
        Using MyCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
            Dim ds = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(ds) 
        End Using
    End Using
```

And I suggest to add the Import directive to avoid the lenghty namespace prefix for every single OleDb variable

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes you suggested but I'm still receiving the same error: "Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only." at the "MyCommand.Fill(ds)" line?

Comment: Sorry I see now that your  testFile is probably a global variable of FileUpload type. Right? In this case did you have saved the file posted? See the example in the [FileUpload.HasFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: I don't declare testFile as a global variable, it's the input field the user adds their file to. Do i need to save the posted file? The server I'm working with does not allow write permissions, so I was trying to avoid that. I had tried a different method here: [Previous Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412936/cant-find-referenced-sheet-in-excel-file-while-trying-to-read-from-a-webpage-in/15413972?noredirect=1#15413972) and got no where which is why I tried a different approach.

Comment: Well, I think that you need to write down somewhere that file, you should have some subfolder of your root site folder that is available to being written. Of course you need to check with your hosting service or the system administrator of your organization.

Comment: Found that the error was because my connection string was for excel 2003 and my file was 2007. I fixed this and am now getting the same error as before "Can't find [Sheet1$]". I take it this is because I have not saved the file?

Comment: I suggest you to try with a local IIS where you could easily check if it works after saving the file.